# Как применить изменения в git на сервере автоматически?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-push

У меня есть сервер, на котором залит код сайта. Там я инициализировал git и добавил все файлы. После - клонировал код локально, добавил изменения в git, сделал коммит, отправил. Версия в git на сервере поменялась, но ее изменения не применились. То есть, например, файлы, которые я удалил локально, стали неинициализированными к созданию на сервере. Чтобы это решить, я прописал 
    git reset --hard
на сервере, и изменения локального коммита применились. Как автоматизировать этот процесс, или поменять алгоритм так, чтобы такие изменения применялись автоматически?

Answer (score 1):

Учитывая что, во-первых, для обновления веб-сервера, зачастую нужна его остановка или перезапуск, а, во-вторых, разработчики могут коммитить в любое время, я бы предложил написать скрипт обновления из git с перезапуском и поставить его на cron раз в сутки ночью или когда меньше всего подключения.

**UPD** для тестового сервера

По этой ссылке есть подробное описание: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764380/how-to-push-to-a-non-bare-git-repository

Вкратце - нужно установить свойство репозитория `receive.denyCurrentBranch` в значение  `updateInstead`. Тогда при пуше в текущую ветку рабочая копия будет автоматически обновляться.

Comment: Разработчик я один. Мне нужно тестировать сайт, который будет лежать на сервере - такова специфика. Поэтому нужно достичь того, чтобы изменения применялись сразу после пуша. Веб сервер обновляется постоянно и автоматически - это не является проблемой.

Comment: @sntgl, дополнил ответ.

Comment: я бы в баре пушил и забирал коммит в рабочую скриптом

Comment: Нужны подробности того, как вы забирали. Возможно, был конфликт, и вы его просто не разрешили. Это возможно, если удаляемые файлы были локально изменены на тестовом сервере.

Comment: Никаких изменений и на сервере не было. Конфликтов не встретил - в этом уверен. Вписал receive.denyCurrentBranch updateInstead. Теперь даже пушнуть на сервер не дает. Совсем уже отчаялся.

Comment: С каким сообщением не дает пушить?